# How to set WinHttp Proxy to Direct Access using WinHttpGetDefaultProxyConfiguration

Tags: c#, proxy, netsh

Currently im setting the [WinHttpGetDefaultProxyConfiguration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384113.aspx) using PInvoke from c# in an Application.

When setting the WinHttp Proxy using [Netsh](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731131(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_3), you can disable it again by calling "reset proxy" which sets it to "DIRECT".

Im struggling to find a way to set "DIRECT" through the WinHttpGetDefaultProxyConfiguration.
How would i go about Resetting the Proxy Config to "Direct"?
Any Advice or hints in the right direction are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this might help. I came across this project today.

https://github.com/chentiangemalc/ProxyUtils

Answer (score 0):

Today i spent more time looking at all the options for setting up the Proxy and i missed the fact that the `WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO` object contains a flag `WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY` which should in theory set the WinHTTP Proxy to disabled.